# How do I setup an Apache ProxyPass / Reverse Proxy while listening on an alternate port?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I had Apache configuration which was using a ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse with the following example syntax:

```
ProxyPass /myprog http://localhost:8080/myprog
ProxyPassReverse /myprog http://localhost:8080/myprog
```

Then, I moved Apache from port 80, to 8880, and put another web server on port 80.  I can access some things correctly now on port 8880 - those files which are hosted directly on Apache.  But my proxy pass (to Tomcat) now fails when I try to access it at: http://some.domain:8880/myprog.

How do I correct the ProxyPass/Reseverse to account for the port change?  (I assumed, perhaps natively, the port spec was implicit...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your configuration on a `VirtualHost` tag.

```
<VirtualHost *:8880>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /myprog http://localhost:8080/myprog
    ProxyPassReverse /myprog http://localhost:8080/myprog    
</VirtualHost>
```